# Sum of (n) Dice in Python

Tags: python

> Define a function dice(n) that returns the sum of a random roll of n 6-sided dice. Example output shown here:

```
In []: dice(5)
Roll was 16
```

---

I can't seem to figure this out, even thought its probably something relatively simple.

```
def dice(n):
    rolls = []
    rolls += [random.choice([1,7])]
    for rolls in range (n):
        return 'Roll was', sum(rolls)
```

This is the third thing I have tried. But I'm still really new to coding, so I have no idea how to fix it. the error code I got is 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Please show your efforts, SO is not a code writing service

Comment: Python has `for`-loops, surely?

Comment: In the very simplest answer, you'll want to loop N times adding a random number (between 1 and 6) to a running total. You can do this in a one-liner if you look up list comprehensions, and it won't require learning anything particularly complex or Python-specific.

Comment: yes, this is an exercise with 'for loops'

Comment: At least show that you defined the function

Comment: [Edit] your question. Code should not go in the comments like this that, please

Comment: I kind of don't want to upvote anyone's answer because this is just a "gimme teh codez" question, but it looks like it could turn into a "how many different ways can we do it" party.

Comment: I don't really want any specific answer. I have been working on it for at least an hour, so I knew I needed to ask someone.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy if you try a bit :

```
def dice(number_of_dice):
    final_sum = 0
    for i in range(0,number_of_dice):
        final_sum += random.randint(1,6)
    return final_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def dice(n):
    return sum(random.randint(1,6) for _ in range(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> dice_item = lambda: randint(1, 6)                                                                                                                                                                          
>>> 
>>> def dice(n):
...     return sum(dice_item() for y in range(n))                                                                                                                                                                

>>> dice(5)
19
```

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice([1,7])` chooses a random element from the list `[1,7]`.  `random.randint(1,6)` will give you a random number between 1 and 6, inclusive.

Instead of doing `rolls += ...`, you should do `rolls.append(...)`.

Then, when you are doing your `for` loop, you're reusing the name `rolls`, which gets rid of the value that was in it previously.

Also, you should be rolling your dice in a `for` loop and then calculating the sum outside of that loop

```
def dice(n):
    rolls = []
    for _ in range(n):
        rolls.append(random.randint(1, 6))
    return sum(rolls)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be the correct way to code it, but this is what I ended up with.

def dice(n):

```
print 'Roll was', sum([random.randrange(1,7) for _ in range(n)])
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: That's wrong. Your task was to `return` the value, not to print it.

Comment: When I put return and not print the code wouldn't show 'roll was'.

Comment: You have to put your code in a function called `dice` and print the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this would do:

```
import numpy as np

def dice(n):
    rolls = np.random.randint(5, size = (1, n)) + 1
    return rolls.sum()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   dice(10)
```